# Undefined variable : variable from controller to view

Tags: codeigniter, variables

Hi i dont know why its not any more working.
i got undefinied variable if i try to echo the variable in the view.
Here the controller

```
class save_settings extends CI_Controller {

    function save()
    {
        $data['test'] =  'content';
        $this->load->view('help', $data);
    }      
}
```

and view

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="de">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $test ; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hmm, is it normally simple but i dont know why it doesnt work today

Comment: Can you check and show what exactly in your `help` view ?

Comment: Its 400 lines big but i try now just simple html code and the echo command

Comment: its above in the question and its still undefinied

Comment: Are you sure you are loading the right view and right file ?

Comment: its the correctr file i could print some text and i can see it

Comment: we should avoid to extend this discussion or can you chat if you wannt still try to help

Comment: Its an save function i want echo a variable to debug the save function which doesnt works . so i simpliied the code with an empty view file called help

Comment: There's nothing in your code that would cause the issue, so what is your URL?

Comment: but the simplest code doesnt pass the variable not to view

Comment: In `save()` method, instead put `exit('test123');` and see if it comes up.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/P2XvJMSe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Some issue to check -**

1) Correct `view name` and `path`

2) Correct URL - `/save_settings/save`

3) Try to `print and exit` something to check whether the controller is loading perfectly.

```
function save()
{
    $data['test'] =  'content';
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($data); exit;   //  <== Debug
    $this->load->view('help', $data);
}

// Should give
Array(
  [test] => content
)
```

Comment: how can i check a print in controller ? i thought the print must be in view. i wanted try to check so the variables of the controller

Comment: OK  i 've got now the array output.

Comment: Thats nice. By the way, what was the issue?